# Multiple environments

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a Testcafe project, that needs to run in multiple environments, with different options located in .testcaferc, so something that would allow me to have multiple configuration files is needed.
Currently I don't see how this could be implemented.

What would be the best approach to solve this.

Comment: You really need multiple `.testcaferc.json` files? In my experience, multiple environments usually means either multiple test/staging envrionments, which usually equals to different URLs and some other config values, and test data perhaps, or multiple language versions. Both of these don't really require multiple `.testcaferc.json` files. Can you elaborate more on what you need to achive with multiple `.testcaferc.json` files?

Comment: I will probably solve it by deploying separate .testcaferc on each env. Thx anyway.